# How to get output specific element from json url output

Tags: php

I've some problem with getting  result out of json. using php.

Here is my json link : [Json link](http://2strok.com/test/test.json)

I want to take out from json file: title, place, (images:mediumPreviewUrl) and smallMapUrl :)

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://2strok.com/test/test.json');
$obj = json_decode($json);
if($obj->result === 'ok') {
foreach($obj->{'model_data'} as $data) {
    echo $data->{'title'}."<br />";
     }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: to get out the result.

Comment: Offhand, it doesn't look like the JSON object at that URL has a `result` property.

Comment: Indeed, it has an "ok" property with a boolean value which it looks like you wanted to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you're looking for is `ok`, not `result`. And it contains a boolean, so you can just look for `$obj->ok` instead of comparing it to some specific value.

Also, the complex syntax (`$obj->{'model_data'}`) isn't necessary to access those properties. You can start with this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://2strok.com/test/test.json');
$obj = json_decode($json);
if ($obj->ok) {
    foreach($obj->model_data as $data) {
        echo $data->title."<br />";
    }
}
```

I think you'll be able to get the rest of the properties you want from here.